# How to log into RobinHood with the R package?

Tags: r

I have not seen many resources. The package is RobinHood. It is used to access your portfolio. However with the latest version of the package it requires an mfa code. I'll type the following.

```
RH <- RobinHood(username = "Username", password = "Password")
```

Then I will run this because the mfa code comes from trying to log into a new device via text.  This is the error I get:

```
Error in RobinHood::api_login(username, password, mfa_code) : 
  argument "mfa_code" is missing, with no default
```

How can I create a Robinhood object? Do I have to initiate a new login on an incognito tab to login?

Comment: Did you load the package using `library(RobinHood)` ?

Comment: Apologies. I copied the wrong error. (Forgot to load the library first time). I did then it said, "no mfa_code listed without default" or some such

Comment: Error in RobinHood::api_login(username, password, mfa_code) : 
  argument "mfa_code" is missing, with no default

Comment: [The function takes 3 arguments](https://github.com/JestonBlu/RobinHood/blob/main/R/RobinHood.R): username, password and mfa_code. So you need to supply `mfa_code` from somewhere - presumably there is an external authentication method that generates it.

Comment: I know in earlier versions it was just username and password. But must I log into a new device and have a code texted to me? Then I must supply that text code as the ```mfa_code```? It would seem extra tedious to generate a new login then run the code every time. Only resource I have seen is a Youtube video from QuantRoom.